# Getting extensions that were loaded in the viewer

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there a way to get the loaded extensions?

For example, can I get the measurement extension by doing something like:

```
let m = viewer.Measurement
```

And then invoking the measurement methods like enabling and disabling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, it's with:

```
let MeasureExtension = viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Measure");
```

And to view all the extension you can use `viewer.loadedExtensions`.